# T-tubules in Muscle Cells

Tags: physiology, cardiology, muscles

I understand that T-tubules are common to striated muscles such as skeletal and cardiac muscles (with smooth muscle cells having caveolae) but what precisely (if any) is the difference in the T-tubular systems of skeletal and cardiac muscle cells?

Comment: The Wikipedia article [T-tubule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T-tubule) describes the differences.